# How to concatenate image before classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to use 3channel image for InceptionResNetV2 then concatenate a correspond 1channel image before GlobalAveragePooling2D.

I tried find train_generator file order,build correspond image list in merge_layer()  and concatenate them in layers.Concatenate

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(shuffle=True)

conv_base = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(weights=None,include_top=False , input_shape=(299,299,3))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)

model.add(merge_layer())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(conv_base, merge_layer))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7,activation='softmax')) 
svm_layer = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1.0) 
model.add(svm_layer)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_generator,
                   epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1,
                   validation_data=valid_generator,)
```

But I dont know how to do same action on Val & Test datagenerator

And I'm not sure I can find true train_generator order of shuffle=True